# Remote Application Installation Quotewerks

Tags: installation, windows-server-2019

I am having an issue on my Windows Server 2019 Terminal Server. Im trying to install quotewerks. Im using an installation file that is on another server that i've shared the database for. It appears to install correctly. However when I start the application. Quotewerks immediately goes non-responsive. I spoke to quotewerks and they say it might be related to our network. We've already looked at layout issues and printer configuration issues which are a common cause of this.

Anyone have any idea where I could go from here? I've made sure to fully uninstall and clear any files by following a guide on which registry files to delete and appdata files to remove (backed up reg first). Then i made sure to set the term serv to install mode. ran install as admin. switched back to execute mode, ran app as admin. It does in fact load the database so i know it's communicating with the server because all of the usernames to login appear. But once I log in. BOOM. non-responsive.

Comment: What about your network did they say was the problem? What is quotewerks? Please edit your question giving us more information.